# Tradução estranha: "membro de X dias" e "vistos"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Nas informações de perfil tem essas duas traduções:

[image: perfil]

"Membro de 5 dias" me soa estranho. Não seria "Membro POR 5 dias"?

E também, "vistos 4 mins atrás". Não seria o singular "visto"?

Comment: Os textos foram alterados para "membro há" e "visto".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na área a que te estás a referir, não só existem essas duas traduções estranhas, como uma terceira que na minha opinião também não está da melhor forma:

[image: Captura de Tela]

1. À quanto tempo é membro do site

   Dependendo do que é mais "natural" no Brasil, eu optaria por:

   **Membro à** ou como já referido na pergunta **Membro por**, onde iríamos ler "membro à 2 meses" ou "membro por 2 meses":

   > membro à
2. Contador de visitas ao site e contador de visitas seguidas

   A palavra adequada seria **visitou**, ou em alternativa **visitou por**, onde iríamos ler "visitou 68 dias, 68 consecutivos" ou "visitou por 68 dias, 68 consecutivos":

   > visitou
3. À quanto tempo foi visto no site

   Concordo com a indicação na pergunta, o singular da palavra atual resulta de forma eficaz, onde iríamos ler "**visto** 14 mins atrás":

   > visto

---

A ideia destas três sugestões é manter o sujeito e o tempo verbal igual nos três tópicos, de forma a tornar a leitura o mais natural possível.

**Nota:**
A aplicação do ***por*** parece ser algo comum ao pessoal Brasileiro, pessoalmente não me faz grande confusão, desde que se preserve o tempo verbal e o sujeito para que a leitura tenha alguma lógica em toda a página, quer para o titular da conta quer para quem está a consultar a informação de um utilizador.